# Role of Cu in Corey-House synthesis

Tags: organic-chemistry, organometallic-compounds

What does $\ce{Cu}$ do? And why do we need it? Can we not do $\mathrm{S_N}2$ without it? And is there any other metal that can help in this? Maybe something like $\ce{Ag}$? I'm guessing this because the special thing about $\ce{Cu}$ is that it is worse reducing agent than $\ce{H}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copper is used to avoid [lithium-halogen exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organolithium_reagent#Lithium-Halogen_exchange). **Additional information on that reaction can be found [in this discussion](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/33120/23444).** Organolithiums will often, instead of acting as a nucleophile, form a new organolithium: $$\ce{RLi + R'X <=> RX + R'Li}$$ Using $\ce{Cu(I)}$ allows the formation of an organocuprate, which acts as a nucleophile, allowing alkylation rather than metallation: $$\ce{2RLi + CuX -> LiR2Cu + LiX}$$ $$\ce{LiR2Cu + R'X -> R'R + RCu + LiX}$$ I'm not sure if silver could be used instead; I'm not seeing any reference for it, but I may just not be searching the right terms. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organosilver_chemistry) on organosilver chemistry isn't terribly extensive, but I'm guessing stoichiometric use of silver, while not terribly expensive as transition metals go, would certainly be more so than analogous use of copper.

**Update:**

It seems that analogous chemistry *cannot* be performed with silver or gold. Lithium diorganoargentates ($\ce{LiR2Ag}$) are apparently too unstable. Lithium diorganoaurate ($\ce{LiR2Au}$) complexes are apparently either not good nucleophiles, or the triorganogold(III) ($\ce{R2AuR'}$) intermediate complexes are too stable to perform similar chemistry. This is per [this 2005 paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/ja045659%2B). A fair amount of gold chemistry has come out since then, so I'm not sure how much of this has changed since.

**Second update (though I should have answered this to begin with):**

Also, I'd like to add that this is not an $\text{S}_\text{N}2$ reaction. The organocuprate undergoes oxidative addition into the $\ce{R'X}$ bond. After that, it loses the $\ce{X^-}$ ligand to form $\ce{LiX}$ and $\ce{R2CuR'}$, then undergoes reductive elimination to form $\ce{R'R + CuR}$.

Comment: I see, that helps, but why does RLi undergo that reaction? Isn't R-Li a strongly polarized bond? What kind of bond is it actually? And what reaction is this undergoing?

Comment: The Li-X exchange mechanism isn't really known for sure yet. [This presentation](https://www.princeton.edu/chemistry/macmillan/group-meetings/SL-LiExchange.pdf) from the MacMillan group talks about three proposed mechanisms: radical exchange, nucleophilic attack on the halogen, and a four-centered intermediate. I would guess it doesn't undergo normal nucleophilic attack due to hard-soft acid-base chemistry, i.e. poor orbital overlap. I'm not totally sure, though.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a link to another Chemistry.SE answer about lithium-halogen exchange.